# What are the interactions between mtDNA and nucelus' DNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics, mitochondria

In an exam situation I have been presented with the following question by the teacher:

> What are the interactions between the mitochondrial DNA and the cell's nuclear DNA?

To my knowledge there is no such interaction. At the best you could say that the nuclear genome provides the mitochondria with some proteins and vice versa the mitochondria may participate in intrinsic apoptosis by releasing cytochrome C. Unfortunately this answer was not accepted by the teacher and I was not given an explanation. My question is wheter there is an actual interaction I've never heard of or if maybe the poorly worded question was alluding to something else.

Comment: IMO, the question is rather broad and a little vague. Knowing the subject of the course may help us. What was the subject of the course?

Comment: Hello. I am studying medicine in europe. The exam in question is just a first year Bio & Genetics course.

Comment: Sounds as if you have a good grasp of the biochemistry of mitochondria. Probably better than your instructor, who may be embarrassed at his poor question. Certainly there are no contemporary physical interactions, although if you are considering evolution then mitochondrial genes were lost to the nucleus. Move on.